# Quand utilise-t-on le mot « année » et quand est-ce qu'on utilise « an » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, indications-de-temps

Dans la langue courante, dans quelques instances, j'entend le mot "annee" (avec un accent grave sur la premiere e) mais quelques autres fois, j'entend le mot "an" utilise pour decrire quelque chose que semble avoir le mem sens que "annee."

Quand est-ce qu'il faut utiliser "annee" ou "an," ou est-ce qu'ils sont interchangables?

Comment: Juste une note concernant l'accent : c'est un accent aigu (« année » et pas « annèe ».